# Third order ODE

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

**Hi everyone !**

In the context of a linear algebra course, I need to solve this complex third order ODE using matrices:

$$y''' - iy'' +y'-iy = e^{it} + t$$

I already managed to write the matrix form for the homogeneous equation:

$$ \frac{d}{dt} 
\begin{pmatrix} 
y \\ y'\\ y''\\ 
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
i & -1 & i \\
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
y\\ y'\\ y''\\
\end{pmatrix} $$

I'm stuck at this stage: I don't understand how I need to proceed now...

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve the characteristic equation first: $$r^3-ir^2+r-i=0$$
You can rewrite it as $$r^2(r-i)+(r-i)=(r-i)(r^2+1)=(r-i)^2(r+i)=0$$
Note that the solutions of this equation are similar to the power of the particular solution, so the particular solution must contain a polynomial multiplied with $e^{it}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I tried $$e^{it}(at+b)$$ but i didn't work. Wich degree should my polynomial be ? How do you know that ? Again, thanks for your answer and have a nice evening !

Comment: It has to be equal to the multiplicity of the particular root. In this case, $2$. It's easy to show that you can keep just the $at^2e^{it}$ term, since everything else will cancel. You can follow a logis similar to my reply to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3046675

Answer (score 0):

A good way to solve this linear matrix DE

$$
\dot y(t) = A\cdot y(t) + b(t)
$$

with $y(t) = (y_1(t),y_2(t),y_3(t))^{\dagger},\ \ b(t) = (0,0,e^{i t}+t)^{\dagger}$ is using the Laplace Transform. According to it we have

$$
s Y(s)-y(0) = A Y(s) + B(s)
$$

and then

$$
(sI-A)Y(s) = B(s)+y(0)
$$

and also

$$
Y(s) = (sI-A)^{-1}(B(s)+y(0))
$$

here

$$
s I-A = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 s & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & s & -1 \\
 -i & 1 & s-i \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

and

$$
(s I-A)^{-1} = \frac{1}{(s-i)^2(s+i)}\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 s (s-i)+1 & s-i & 1 \\
 i & s (s-i) & s \\
 i s & i-s & s^2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

and $B(s) = (0,0,\frac{1}{s^2}+\frac{1}{s-i})$ etc.

NOTE

$(sI-A)^{-1}$ gives the determinant of $sI-A$ at the denominator which contains the main expansion factors for the inversion.